# Is there a way to attract a user's attention?

Tags: discussion, chat

I know if I comment after someone, or after their answer or their question, then they will be notified.  But is there are more general way to attract people's attention?  For example (hope he doesn't mind, but he's a mod :-) ) if I do @whuber will that now attract his attention?  Would this work in chat?

For example, sometimes one sees a question that you'd like to flag up for another user (perhaps because you've seen them giving good similar answers before).  I'm digging through some old questions...

Comment: Related questions, http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1303/1036 and http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1190/1036. The answer is no, and pings are local to a particular comment thread (and chat room with recent participation from the user). I suspect it is more clearly laid out somewhere else (probably on SO.meta would be a good place to check).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get somebody's attention:

- If you need a moderator--just some moderator--flag a question, comment, or answer.
- If you need a specific moderator, flag something relevant and in the "other" box of the flag dialog explain whom you are trying to reach (and why).
- Add a comment to their question or answer.  (Please don't do this for just any question or answer: use a question or answer that is relevant to the reason for getting their attention.)
- If they have participated in a comment thread, "ping" them using the "@" construct as illustrated in the question.  (NB: pinging does *not* work in questions, answers, nor in comments if the user has not already participated in that comment thread.)
- If the user has participated in chat, you may ping them from that chat room.
- If you have sufficient reputation, you may create a new chat room and invite users to join it.
- Moderators may "super-ping" individuals from chat rooms: it works like a ping but does not require the individual ever to have been part of the chat before.  The mechanism to do this is a little intricate so it's not often done.
- Moderators may contact users privately by e-mail.  Copies are automatically sent to the SE team and all other mods for the site: this is the mechanism used to address serious problems in usage or behavior.

Comment: Succinctly stated and well-put.

Comment: Can I get myself's attention by doing @StephaneLaurent ?

Comment: Answer: no. :-)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I think the *real* test is to try your first comment again, now that you've actually participated in the comment stream. Of course, it's all to satisfy idle curiosity. :-)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am impressed by the success of your comment

Comment: @cardinal Same result: no notification :)